# What is the probability of getting the exact number of expected digits ($0-9$) in $10^6$ digits of $\pi$?

Tags: combinatorics, random, pi

I noticed that at $1$ million digits of $\pi$, none of the digits has the "perfect" expected $100{,}000$ occurrences.  My question is what is the probability (if the digits are truly random) of at least one of the digits having the "perfect" # of occurrences (in this case $100{,}000$)?  To be more accurate as one reader pointed out, what is the probability of $1$ million randomly generated digits from $0$ to $9$ having this property?

Comment: Very slim, I would think.  The probability of getting exactly $500000$ heads in a million flips of a fair coin is vanishingly small.

Comment: I'd also like to add that any sequence of digits is just as likely as another. For example, $\dots 9999999999\dots $ is just as likely as $\dots 4281097635\dots$.

Comment: Also, unlike 1 million coin flips which only has "one chance" to get it exact, here we have 10 chances but I am not sure if it is as simple as just calculating the probability of one digit "hitting the nail on the head" and then multiplying that by $10$ cuz if one digit is "lagging", that forces the others to be higher.

Comment: David, to answer your question, it's not that simple. Just multiplying by 10 would result in some double-counting related to cases where *more* than one digit occurs exactly 100,000 times. Since these cases probably don't happen too often, multiplying by ten is probably a decent approximation, though something of an overestimate. My answer below uses the inclusion-exclusion formula to deal with this double-counting problem in an exact way.

Comment: I might suggest a rewording of the question. The probability you ask for is $0$, since $\pi$'s decimal representation is what it is, and you know with certainty that this doesn't happen. You could instead ask, "if we take one $1{,}000{,}000$ uniformly randomly distributed digits from 0--9, what is the probability that at least one of the digits will occur exactly $100{,}000$ times?"

Comment: Well I did not say the first million digits of pi but I agree the question could have been worded better.  I think most readers of this question knew what I meant but thanks for being exact.  That is a good quality most of the time.

Comment: There are people who research the statistics of the actual digit distribution in the number $\pi$, so it's not crazy to be asking questions like this while having $\pi$ specifically in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First an exact answer, then an approximate one.

The number of sequences in which the digit $0$ appears exactly 100,000 times is $\binom{1000000}{100000}9^{900000}$.

The number of sequences in which $0$ and $1$ each appear exactly 100,000 times is $\binom{1000000}{100000}\binom{900000}{100000}8^{800000}$.

In general, the number of sequences in which the first $k$ digits each appear exactly 100,000 times is 
$$ (10 - k)^{1000000 - 100000k} \prod_{i=0}^{k-1} \binom{1000000 - 100000i}{100000}.$$

Using the inclusion-exclusion formula, the probability of at least one digit appearing exactly 100,000 times is
$$10^{-1000000}\sum_{k = 1}^{10} (-1)^{k-1} \binom{10}{k}  (10 - k)^{1000000 - 100000k} \prod_{i=0}^{k-1} \binom{1000000 - 100000i}{100000}.$$

I'm not sure what this number works out to be (though it seems feasible to put it into a computer), but if you call $X$ the number of times you get the digit $1$, it can be approximated by a normal variable with mean 100,000 and standard deviation $[1000000 (0.1)(0.9)]^{1/2} = 300$. So the probability that $X = 100000$ will be quite close to $\frac{1}{300\sqrt{2\pi}}$. I think the probability of more than one digit occurring exactly 100,000 times is relatively small, so I would expect the answer to be quite close to $10$ times this number, namely $\frac{1}{30\sqrt{2\pi}}$. This estimate can be improved by using a normal (or Stirling) approximation for the second term in the formula above.

EDIT: The first-level approximation gives you a probability of 1.3298%. The more accurate second-level approximation gives you a probability of 1.3218%.

EDIT: Using the full inclusion-exclusion formula, I get $1.321827895126123\%$.

Comment: All these answers are very good and informative so I "upvoted" them all but I am giving user187373 the checkmark cuz he answered first and seems to need the reputation points more than the other two people that answered.

Comment: @David I appreciate the praise very much. However, please feel free to accept whichever answer is most useful to you.

Comment: Well Tony K's was the easier for me to understand but I can see the other answers required work so I gave credit to all.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is equivalent to throwing $N=10^6$ balls into $m=10$ urns (equiprobably) and asking for the probability that at least one urn $i$ has $X_i=N/m$ balls.

This can be approximated (Poissonization) as $m$ iid Poisson variables $Y_i$ with mean $\lambda=E(X_i)=N/m$

The probability that one given urn gets $Y_i=\lambda$ balls is

$$p = \frac{\lambda^\lambda}{\lambda!} e^{-\lambda} \approx \frac{\lambda^\lambda}{(\lambda/e)^\lambda \sqrt{2 \pi \lambda}} e^{-\lambda}= \sqrt{ \frac{m}{2 \pi N}} \approx 0.00126$$

The probabilty that some ball gets $Y_i=\lambda$ is $ 1-(1-p)^m \approx $ (which can be approximated by $m \, p$ -  if you want to).

Then, the desired probability is $0.012544\cdots$

Both approximations (the Poissonization and the Stirling formula) can be refined. Anyway, it's seen that the probability decreases as $1/\sqrt{N}$. Notice, BTW, that this gives the probability of "success" for fixed $N=10^6$ , not for all "tries" $n\le N$ - which would be a more difficult problem.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with the Poisson approximation. It's only valid when $\lambda$ is relatively small. I don't think you can get away with $\lambda = 10^5$ when $N = 10^6$ only. Also, the $X_i$'s aren't independent. For example, knowing that $X_1 = 100000$ makes it about 0.6% more likely that you'll have $X_2 = 100000$.

Comment: Yes, the approximation works better when both $N$ and $m$ are large. That $Y$ (the Poisson vars) are independent while $X$ (the true variables) aren't, is obvious, but that's part of the approximation, and the error turns negligible in the above limit. Strictly speaking: $X$ has the same distribution as $Y$ conditioned to its sum: $\sum Y_i = \sum E(Y_i)$

Answer (score 2):

Consider a specific digit ($7$, say). The probability of $k$ $7$'s in $n$ random digits is (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Probability_mass_function))

$$\binom{n}{k}\left(\frac{1}{10}\right)^k\left(\frac{9}{10}\right)^{n-k}$$

With $n=1,000,000$ and $k=100,000$, Wolfram Alpha [evaluates this as 0.001329806480909191...](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1000000%21%2F%28100000%21*900000%21%29*%280.1%5E100000%29*%280.9%5E900000%29)

This agrees with user187373's approximation $\frac{1}{300\sqrt{2\pi}} \approx 0.001329807601338108...$ to six significant figures, which supports user187373's final probability of $\frac{1}{30\sqrt{2\pi}}$ (about $1$ in $75$).